# Issues calculating double intergral

Tags: calculus, physics

> Calculate $$\iint_\Omega(x^2+y^2)^b\,dxdy$$
>   where $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,:\, x^2+y^2<a^2\}$ and $b>0$ is a real constant.

I'm having trouble calculating the following, it's from a past exam that I'm doing for revision . I think I need to convert to polar co-ordinates and got an answer but it was $\dfrac{a^{4b+4}}{2b+2}$

Comment: Go to polar. We want to integrate $r^{2b}r\,dr\,d\theta$ over the disk. This is $\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^a r^{2b}r\,dr\,d\theta$. My guess is that you forgot about the $\theta$ and also integrated from $r=0$ to $a^2$.

Comment: please post your calculation

Comment: @AndréNicolas that was my issue i was integrating from r = 0 to $a^2$ thank you

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

$\int\int_{R} (x^2+y^2)^b dxdy$ in the Domain $x^2+y^2\le a^2$ with b>0

==>

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{a} r^{2b}rdrd\theta$$

Which when you evaluate gives

you

$$=\dfrac{\pi a^{2b+2}}{b+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

convert to polar - the angle integral gives a factor of $2\pi$ and don't forget that $dx\;dy \to rdr\; d\theta$

$$I = 2\pi \int_0^a r^{2b+1} dr =\frac{2\pi a^{2b+2}}{2b+2}=\frac \pi {b+1} a^{2b+2}  $$